# How long are the lunar cycles in Elder Scrolls?

Tags: moon, the-elder-scrolls

When doing research on Khajiit and learning about their Furstocks, I started wondering if there was a predictable lunar cycle in the elder scrolls that you could put on calenders and use to predict what type baby Khajiit at a certain time will be what type. Is there one?

Comment: As per the [tour], you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I'm waiting to see if I get other answers.

Comment: No worries. I just always like to let new people know pre-emptively. :) We get a lot of hit-and-runs here.

Answer (score 2):

First, there are of course two moons. Secondly, [this fellow](https://www.reddit.com/r/teslore/comments/9fe8d2/moon_cycle_of_nirn/) has figured some things out. Long story short, it's mildly inconsistent between games, but it looks like Masser has a cycle of about 24 days, and Secunda is 30 days.

The primary basis is from [this post](https://www.imperial-library.info/content/phases-moon):

> I've been able to learn a bit about how the Moons function in Oblivion (I'm pretty sure it's the same system in Morrowind and Skyrim, but I'd need to check it out more thoroughly).
>
> First observation is that the Moons rise from the Northeast and set to the Southeast.
>
> Masser has a regular cycle of 24 days, each divided into eight sections lasting three days each, corresponding to: New, Waxing Crescent, First Quarter, Waxing Gibbous, Full, Waning Gibbous, Second Quarter, and Waning Crescent. Masser always rises at dusk, reaches its highest point at midnight, and sets at dawn.
>
> Secunda's orbit is divided into the same eight divisions corresponding to the above descriptions (New, Waxing Crescent, etc.). However, unlike Masser, Secunda reaches its highest point in the sky at eight different times, which are (sequentially): 12 AM, 8 PM, 4 PM, 12 PM, 8 AM, 4 AM.
>
> Another difference is that the phases of Secunda either appear three days in a row (like Masser), or four days. In the end, Secunda's cycle lasts approximately 30 days, from what I can gather, while Masser's lasts 24 days. And yes, Secunda can be full at noon... I'm afraid that if I keep on trying to make sense of this, I might end up a lunatic!